# Как перевести координаты в место

Tags: python, геолокация

в ходе работы появилась потребность узнать в каком городе(районе) находится пользователь приложения, и все что я нашел это только код что бы узнать свой ip

```
import geocoder
g = geocoder.ip('me')
print(g.latlng)
```

Теперь новый вопрос: как мне получить название города по IP?

Comment: Судя по коду, наоборот, вы из своего ip получаете широту и долготу. И что такое "перетворить"?

Comment: https://geocoder.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У объекта, который возвращает `geocoder.ip` есть полезные свойства:

- `address`
- `city`
- `country`
- `state`

и другие

Обращаться так:

```
import geocoder
g = geocoder.ip('me')
print(g.city)
```

Comment: О, что-то я сразу короткие варианты не нашёл. Удобный модуль.

Answer (score 3):

Смотрите, что есть в `g.geojson` (я смотрю в Google Colab):

```
{'features': [{'geometry': {'coordinates': [-95.8608, 41.2619],
    'type': 'Point'},
   'properties': {'address': 'Council Bluffs, Iowa, US',
    'city': 'Council Bluffs',
    'country': 'US',
    'hostname': '63.121.122.34.bc.googleusercontent.com',
    'ip': '34.122.121.63',
    'lat': 41.2619,
    'lng': -95.8608,
    'ok': True,
    'org': 'AS15169 Google LLC',
    'postal': '51502',
    'raw': {'city': 'Council Bluffs',
     'country': 'US',
     'hostname': '63.121.122.34.bc.googleusercontent.com',
     'ip': '34.122.121.63',
     'loc': '41.2619,-95.8608',
     'org': 'AS15169 Google LLC',
     'postal': '51502',
     'readme': 'https://ipinfo.io/missingauth',
     'region': 'Iowa',
     'timezone': 'America/Chicago'},
    'state': 'Iowa',
    'status': 'OK'},
   'type': 'Feature'}],
 'type': 'FeatureCollection'}
```

Город тут лежит в `g.geojson['features'][0]['properties']['city']`: `Council Bluffs`.

Но можно и короче через `g.city` город получить, как написано в другом ответе. В общем, вся инфа там есть, читайте доки.

Comment: Да, очень все запутано, я использую второй метод, но все равно спасибо вам за наданную мне помощь)

Answer (score 0):

Если через IPinfo.io, то https://ipinfo.io/IP_address/city?token=TOKEN
Этот запрос выдаст только город, без остальной ненужной информации. Токен с 50к запросов бесплатный, потом можно перейти на платный план с 250к.
Пример без токена: https://ipinfo.io/1.1.1.1/city
И тогда не нужно координаты в город конвертить.